# Display Mongo user data in EJS file with node/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm running node/express/mongoose/mongo and I'm trying to display a logged-in user's info in their account page.

In my user controller file, I'm trying to access their Mongo User ID to then look up the full User object, load that object into a const, and pass that object into the render of an EJS file.

```
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports.account = async (req, res) => {
    const userID = req.user._id;
    const { user } = await User.findById(userID);
    res.render('app/account', { user })
}
```

When I console.log userID, I get "new ObjectId("61d321284256dffb7e869e8f")" (shouldn't I just get the number string?).
When I console.log user.email when hard coding findByID('61d321284256dffb7e869e8f'), I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined".

Really lost on this one so I appreciate any help here.

Comment: What is the `req` variable and its value?

Comment: req.user._id is retrieved from passport (http://www.passportjs.org/). when I console.log(req.user._id) i get new ObjectId("61d321284256dffb7e869e8f") but I only want the string, not sure how to parse that.

Comment: I think there is a `toString()` function (or something similar) to get the _string_ value.

Answer (score 1):

Answered - added `toString` in the code and also found that I used,

```
module.exports.account = async (req, res) => {
    const userID = req.user._id.toString();
    const user = await User.findById(userID);
    res.render('app/account', { user })
}
```